# How to add a few comments to the repository files before commitment

Tags: git, githooks

Every commit I should add to file few lines, for example

`// Author - John Doe`

`// email - john@example.com`

Is there any possibility to make this routine via git hooks? I've found a solution to add these lines with pre-commit hook, but after hook fires, files move to unstaged

Comment: This information is already included in the commit, why do you want to duplicate it?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk it's just for example, I have a few lines that should be included in each file in git repo, also I have such script, but I have to run it manually before commit `$ add-lines.sh && git commit -m "Commit"`. The question is how to automate this routine

Comment: Isn't it possible to use `git commit --signoff`or `git commit -S` that add these information?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to edit and automatically add some
files to the staging area before every commit. In order to do so you
have to run and `git add` in `pre-commit` hook like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "add automatically\n" >> file
git add file
```

Comment: It's whatever you want to be,  it's just an example.  I don't know how your script really looks like.  The point is you have to  run `git add` on the  file  if you want it to be committed.

Comment: but I've alredy run script which adds everything what i need, but I should run it manually, is there any approach to automate this task?

Comment: First you said `I've found a solution to add these lines with pre-commit hook, but after hook fires, files move to unstaged` - this is why I suggested adding `git add` to your script. Now you're asking about automating - I also said what hook you should use.